# Unknown Code Error involving Python float(sys.argv[1])

Tags: python, ubuntu, python-3.x, arguments, sys

I am working on a Farenheiht-Celsius converter in Python 3. I have some example code given to me that doesn't work, but I don't know why. Here is my code:

```
#!home/andres/Documents/Executables
import sys
f = int(sys.argv[1])
print (f, "degrees farenheit is equal to", )
print (5.0/9*(f - 32), "degrees Celsius.")
```

Of course, I obtain a syntax error as follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/andres/Documents/Executables/f2c.py", line 3, in <module>
    f = int(sys.argv[1])
IndexError: list index out of range
>>>
```

Some stuff to note:

1. I have a (sketchy) understanding of the sys.argv command, which is used in conjunction with command line arguments.
2. My teacher intends for me to tun this code as such.

   $ ./f2c.py 212
   212.0 degrees farehheit is equal to 100.0 degrees celsius.

(Yes, I know the above section is not showing up as code, but I am not sure how to fix it.)
3. I am running Ubuntu, but am still getting used to it. Pardon my ignorance.

Think that's about it. Thanks!

EDIT: Here is my shell session, which may help:

```
andres@Beta:~/Documents/Executables$ ./f2c.py
bash: ./f2c.py: /bin/env: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
andres@Beta:~/Documents/Executables$ chmod +x f2c.py
andres@Beta:~/Documents/Executables$ ./f2c.py 12
bash: ./f2c.py: /bin/env: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
andres@Beta:~/Documents/Executables$
```

Comment: using `sys.argv` in an interactive interpreter doesn't make much/any sense.  It only makes sense if you run the script as instructed, since `sys.argv` contains the command-line instructions from the shell.

Comment: Your shebang `#!home/andres/Documents/Executables` does not make much sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you are running your code within the interpreter, either using an IDE or the python prompt. This will not work as sys.argv relies on calling the program from the terminal command line. 
When I do so your code works correctly,

```
[myself@localhost ~]$ python f2c.py 12
12 degrees farenheit is equal to -11.1111111111 degrees Celsius.
```

To run it as ./f2c.py you need to do two things,

edit your code to resemble the following

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
f = int(sys.argv[1])
print (f, "degrees farenheit is equal to", )
print (5.0/9*(f - 32), "degrees Celsius.")
```

This is a command for linux shells such as bash to call the 'env' program and tell it that we need to use python to run it

Secondly, we need to make the file executable, this is done as

```
chmod +x f2c.py
```

Now you can call as follows

```
[myself@localhost ~]$ ./f2c.py 12
12 degrees farenheit is equal to -11.1111111111 degrees Celsius.
```

BTW, the correct spelling is Fahrenheit.

Comment: Note that on Windows, you can already just run it as `./f2c.py` without either of those steps (assuming you let the Python installer install the launcher and hook it up properly, which I think is the default in at least CPython 3.3 and 3.4 from python.org). I realize the OP is using Ubuntu, I just wanted this comment here in case any Windows users with the same problem come here and want to know why `chmod` gives them errors and why the shebang is having no effect and so on…

Comment: andres@Beta:~/Documents/Executables$ ./f2c.py
bash: ./f2c.py: /bin/env: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
andres@Beta:~/Documents/Executables$ chmod +x f2c.py
andres@Beta:~/Documents/Executables$ ./f2c.py 12
bash: ./f2c.py: /bin/env: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
andres@Beta:~/Documents/Executables$

Comment: @Qu0rk Not sure how that occurred. I think the problem may be how you are running python. What does the command 'which python' display for you? How did you install and run python? Did you copy the file over from windows? That can also mess up #!/bin/env python . I pasted the entire script in my answer for clarification

Comment: Installed python using sudo apt-get install python3-minimal

I also installed the Python IDLE from the Ubuntu store. I copied this file from a .pdf of the book I am learning from. Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: Can you try copying the script I have in my answer and see if that runs? Sometimes if a file was made under linux or windows copying can cause weird things to happen. Windows and linux have different line endings.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `/usr/bin/env`? I don't run Ubuntu, but it's `/usr/bin/env` on Debian and OS X...

Comment: Ah, maybe. I'm a fedora guy but /bin/env has worked for me. It looks like /usr/bin/env is more standard. I edited my answer to reflect that.